# How to add values from other columns into next columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, multiple-columns

I've pivoted a table and I have a base value, let's say 95%.

The schema is like

```
Name, BaseValue, Quarter1, Quarter2, etc..
West, 95%      , 0.5%    , -0.2%   , ...
```

I'd like for Quarter 1 to be BaseValue+ Quarter1's initial value ie. 95.5%.

I'd like for Quarter 2 to be Quarter1 + Quarter2's initial value ie. 95.3%.

Here's the setup in SQLFiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78dd3/1

Comment: Do you want to insert those new values to a new field, or into the same field?  A new field would be fairly straightforward addition function and would maintain the existing values.  For example, Quarter1Total.

Comment: I wanted it to be the same field.. My setup to accomplish this is probably totally wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unpivot, get the running totals, pivot back. Assuming the values are of a numeric type and the version used is SQL Server 2012, [here's one way](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bbc80/1) to implement that:

```
WITH UnpivotAndRunningTotals AS (
  SELECT
    Name,
    Attr,
    Value = SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Attr)
  FROM atable
  UNPIVOT (
    Value FOR Attr IN (BaseValue, Quarter1, Quarter2, Quarter3, Quarter4)
  ) AS u
)
SELECT
  Name,
  BaseValue, Quarter1, Quarter2, Quarter3, Quarter4
FROM UnpivotAndRunningTotals
PIVOT (
  MAX(Value) FOR Attr IN (BaseValue, Quarter1, Quarter2, Quarter3, Quarter4)
) AS p
;
```

Answer (score 0):

With my comment above, I'll assume you want to do this and maintain the existing column values.  The solution is a simple UPDATE using the + operator.

```
ALTER TABLE ADD [4Q13Total] FLOAT

UPDATE TABLE
SET [4Q13TOTAL] = [BASEOCC] + [4Q13]
```

You could also SELECT the values, if you'd like.

```
SELECT [BASEOCC] + [4Q13] AS [Q1Total]
```

Comment: Yeah I just want have the results run as one query, with those same columns

Comment: Try the SELECT query then as a second query - that will preserve your original data but allow you to total the columns and return that result as your dataset.  You could also CREATE TABLE with a timestamp, use a temporary table, etc.  There are numerous ways to then use that data.